# most recent version of bouncy castle is required for Authentication error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bouncycastle, java-17

Everything works fine on my local but when I deploy on AWS ECS fargate . I am getting this error while trying to migrate from JDK 11 to JDK 17 . I have updated to recenet versions of aws-java-sdk as well as bouncy castle.
How can I fix this issue?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: A more recent version of Bouncy castle is required for authenticated encryption.
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CryptoConfigurationV2.checkBountyCastle(CryptoConfigurationV2.java:379)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CryptoConfigurationV2.checkCryptoMode(CryptoConfigurationV2.java:366)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CryptoConfigurationV2.<init>(CryptoConfigurationV2.java:68)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CryptoConfigurationV2.<init>(CryptoConfigurationV2.java:47)
```

I have tried updating all the maven libraries including onces involved here aws-java-sdk version 1.12.552

and bouncy castle bcprov and bcpkix with versions bcpkix-jdk18on-177.jar and bcpkix-jdk15to18-177.jar.

Answer (score 0):

This seems related to spring fat jar and jdk 17
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=JDK-8313742

Answer (score 0):

The bouncy castle has the problem with jdk between 15-18 I guess, as they mention they did update the dependency
[Here is the bouncy castle latest patch](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html)

but as my post below prisma scan still have found issue with them, after using the latest version.

[My post](https://hhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/77791745/prisma-scan-openjdk17-issue-cve-2022-45146-bouncy-castle-1-0-2-3-1-0-2-4ttps://)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).