# Prisma scan openjdk17 issue CVE-2022-45146 Bouncy Castle 1.0.2.3 1.0.2.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, bouncycastle, java-17

The prisma scan shown the vulnerabilities as below, been trying all the latest docker openjdk17 image, still unable to fix it.

```
"vulnerabilities": [
            {
                "id": "CVE-2022-45146",
                "status": "fixed in 1.0.2.4",
                "cvss": 5.5,
                "vector": "CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:N/A:N",
                "description": "An issue was discovered in the FIPS Java API of Bouncy Castle BC-FJA before 1.0.2.4. Changes to the JVM garbage collector in Java 13 and later trigger an issue in the BC-FJA FIPS modules where it is possible for temporary keys used by the module to be zeroed out while still in use by the module, resulting in errors or potential information loss. NOTE: FIPS compliant users are unaffected because the FIPS certification is only for Java 7, 8, and 11.",
                "severity": "medium",
                "packageName": "java",
                "packageVersion": "17.0.9",
                "link": "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-45146",
                "riskFactors": [
                    "Attack complexity: low",
                    "Exploit exists - POC",
                    "Has fix",
                    "Medium severity"
                ],
                "impactedVersions": [
                    "\u003e=13.0.0"
                ],
                "publishedDate": "2022-11-21T12:30:17Z",
                "discoveredDate": "2024-01-19T13:40:13Z",
                "fixDate": "2023-12-15T11:55:32Z",
                "layerTime": "2024-01-17T04:39:42Z",
                "packagePath": "/usr/lib/jvm/zulu17-ca-amd64/bin/java",
                "layerInstruction": "RUN |2 ZULU_REPO_VER=1.0.0-3 ZULU_REPO_SHA256=d08d9610c093b0954c6b278ecc628736e303634331641142fa5096396201f49c /bin/sh -c apt-get -qq update \u0026\u0026     apt-get -qq -y --no-install-recommends install gnupg software-properties-common locales curl tzdata \u0026\u0026     echo \"en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8\" \u003e\u003e /etc/locale.gen \u0026\u0026     locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 \u0026\u0026     apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0xB1998361219BD9C9 \u0026\u0026     curl -sLO https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/zulu-repo_${ZULU_REPO_VER}_all.deb \u0026\u0026     echo \"${ZULU_REPO_SHA256} zulu-repo_${ZULU_REPO_VER}_all.deb\" | sha256sum --strict --check - \u0026\u0026     dpkg -i zulu-repo_${ZULU_REPO_VER}_all.deb \u0026\u0026     apt-get -qq update \u0026\u0026     echo \"Package: zulu17-*\\nPin: version 17.0.9-*\\nPin-Priority: 1001\" \u003e /etc/apt/preferences \u0026\u0026     apt-get -qq -y --no-install-recommends install zulu17-jre-headless=17.0.9-* \u0026\u0026     apt-get -qq -y purge --auto-remove gnupg software-properties-common curl \u0026\u0026     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* zulu-repo_${ZULU_REPO_VER}_all.deb # buildkit"
            }
        ]
```

Anyone have any clue to fix this? I am guessing this is the jdk issue?

Been trying few of the openjdk17 docker image, still have the same error and also did tried to add this dependency in pom file.

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bctls-jdk15to18</artifactId>
        <version>1.77</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bctls-fips</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bc-fips</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the openjdk17 docker image currently using.

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-debian:17-jre-headless-latest
```

Comment: As the NVD entry says, the problem exists for this BCFIPS on _all_ OpenJDK 13 up, so different 17s are utterly useless and unless you go back to 12 (no longer available) or 11 (still LTS) you are stuck. However, as it also says, BCFIPS isn't _validated_ on Java above 11 anyway, so why are you using it on 17? That makes your application _worse_.

Comment: Plus as I read https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bctls-fips/1.0.18 you should already be getting bc-fips 1.0.2.4 with the fix!

Comment: Do not use images for text information in this site.

Comment: As already suggested, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Comment: Actually these code are not written by me, I am just helping to fix the issue and I did try this dependency before yet still getting that error. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bctls-fips/1.0.18